# Create a processing view using Fluent BQL

Tags: acumatica

I'm creating a new custom processing screen and would like to use Fluent BQL, however, I can't seem to get the standard processing UI (process buttons, toolbar actions) when I use Fluent BQL with ProcessingView

```
        public SelectFrom<APPayment>.
           InnerJoin<APContact>.On<APContact.contactID.IsEqual<APPayment.remitContactID>>.
           Where<
               APPayment.cashAccountID.IsEqual<APStaleDatedCheckFilter.cashAccountID.FromCurrent>.
               And<APPayment.adjDate.IsLessEqual<APStaleDatedCheckFilter.cutoffDate.FromCurrent>>.
               And<APPayment.cleared.IsEqual<False>>.
               And<APPayment.released.IsEqual<True>>.
               And<APPayment.status.IsEqual<APDocStatus.closed>>.
               And<APPayment.docType.IsEqual<APDocType.quickCheck>>.
               And<APRegisterExt.usrStaleDated.IsEqual<False>>
               >.ProcessingView DetailsView;
```

However, if I use the BQL style query the processing UI gets created ok:

```
public PXFilteredProcessingJoin<APPayment, APStaleDatedCheckFilter,
   InnerJoin<APContact, On<APContact.contactID, Equal<APPayment.remitContactID>>>,
   Where<APPayment.cashAccountID, Equal<Current<APStaleDatedCheckFilter.cashAccountID>>,
       And<Where<APPayment.adjDate, LessEqual<Current<APStaleDatedCheckFilter.cutoffDate>>,
       And<APPayment.cleared, Equal<False>,
       And<Where<APPayment.released, Equal<True>,
       And<APPayment.status, Equal<APDocStatus.closed>,
       And<Where<APPayment.docType, Equal<APDocType.quickCheck>,
       And<APRegisterExt.usrStaleDated, Equal<False>>>>>>>>>>>> DetailsView;
```

Is there any way to make this work with the fluent syntax?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue here is the requirement of your filter is missing in the Fluent Version. If you add in

> .FilteredBy<APStaleDatedCheckFilter>

to the end of your view, the buttons should reappear:

```
    public SelectFrom<APPayment>.
           InnerJoin<APContact>.On<APContact.contactID.IsEqual<APPayment.remitContactID>>.
           Where<
               APPayment.cashAccountID.IsEqual<APStaleDatedCheckFilter.cashAccountID.FromCurrent>.
               And<APPayment.adjDate.IsLessEqual<APStaleDatedCheckFilter.cutoffDate.FromCurrent>>.
               And<APPayment.cleared.IsEqual<False>>.
               And<APPayment.released.IsEqual<True>>.
               And<APPayment.status.IsEqual<APDocStatus.closed>>.
               And<APPayment.docType.IsEqual<APDocType.quickCheck>>.
               And<APRegisterExt.usrStaleDated.IsEqual<False>>
               >.ProcessingView.FilteredBy<APStaleDatedCheckFilter> DetailsView;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
public PXProcessingViewOf<APPayment>.BasedOn<SelectFrom<APPayment>.InnerJoin<APContact>.On<APContact.contactID.IsEqual<APPayment.remitContactID>>.Where<APPayment.cleared.IsEqual<False>>> DetailsView;
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick.  I tried this but still lose my processing screen UI (no process/process all buttons)

Comment: on the API docs for the ProcessingView type it says "The ProcessingView type is used to define the data view in a graph bound to a processing webpage. A data view of this type includes definitions of two actions, Process and ProcessAll, which are added to the graph and are used to invoke the processing"  However, it doesn't work for me.  I'm on 2020R2 at the moment.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't find an example in the source code.  I was hoping the 'BasedOn' clause would make the difference.